# Calculate in Power BI last week change in revenue by opportunity funnel stage

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm using Power BI to connect to SFDC as my data source for Opportunity table which contains CreateDate, CloseDate, Amount, Stage.

I'm looking to create a measure that calculates the change in Opportunity[amount] for each stage from last week. There is another table "Opportunity History" table that I reference for identify what was the stage of any given opportunity and it's amount last week if there is a record of update, otherwise I assume current opportunity amount and stage are unchanged.

**Here is what I have so far**:
Calculated column on Opportunity table that looks at the history table to identify last weeks stage and amount.Same DAX structure is used for both last week stagename and amount `SELECTEDVALUE('Opportunity History'[StageName])`.

```
LastWeek StageName = 
VAR TodayDate = TODAY()

VAR StartOfLastWeek = TodayDate - 7
VAR EndOfLastWeek = TodayDate - 1
VAR Opp_id = Opportunity[Id]
VAR EarliestCreatedDateLastWeek = 
    CALCULATE(
        MIN('Opportunity History'[CreatedDate]),
        RELATEDTABLE('Opportunity History'),
        'Opportunity History'[CreatedDate] >= StartOfLastWeek,
        'Opportunity History'[CreatedDate] <= EndOfLastWeek
    )

VAR StageName_LW =  IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(EarliestCreatedDateLastWeek)),
        CALCULATE(
            SELECTEDVALUE('Opportunity History'[StageName]),
            'Opportunity History'[OpportunityId] = Opp_id,
            'Opportunity History'[CreatedDate] = EarliestCreatedDateLastWeek
        ),
        Opportunity[StageName]
    )
RETURN StageName_LW
```

Then I aggregate last week's revenue amount from the calc column above into a measure below.

```
Opps Rev LW Stage = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Opportunity[LastWeek Amount]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(Opportunity),
        Opportunity[LastWeek StageName] = MAX(Opportunity[StageName])
    ),
    TREATAS(VALUES(_dim_calendar[Date]), Opportunity[CloseDate])
)
```

Then subtrack from this week's aggregated revenue to identify the week-over-week delta per stage.

```
Opps Rev LW Diff = 
VAR StageRevLW = [Opps Rev LW Stage]
VAR StageRev = [Opps Rev]

RETURN StageRev-StageRevLW
```

The calculations work per stage and date level, however fails at the column total aggregate. See screenshot below.[image]

Is there another way to aggregate the revenue in the matrix? Am I over complicating the calculation?